# Why I get no suitable constructor found error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I follow a course about little accounts app, I start getting error which is related to constructor, whereas the constructor already been created. I copy first an error hereunder & then some of classes related to the error. I'd be grateful for the help

Error:

```
java: no suitable constructor found for PrimaryTransaction(java.util.Date,java.lang.String,
java.lang.String,java.lang.String,double,java.math.BigDecimal)
constructor com.front.domain.PrimaryTransaction.PrimaryTransaction() is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

PrimaryTransaction.java

```
public class PrimaryTransaction {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private Date date;
private String description;
private String type;
private String status;
private double amount;
private BigDecimal availableBalance;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "primary_account_id")
private PrimaryAccount primaryAccount;

public PrimaryTransaction() {
}

public PrimaryTransaction(Date date, String description, String type, String status, double 
amount, BigDecimal availableBalance, PrimaryAccount primaryAccount) {
    this.date = date;
    this.description = description;
    this.type = type;
    this.status = status;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.availableBalance = availableBalance;
    this.primaryAccount = primaryAccount;
}
```

PrimaryAccountDAO.java

```
public interface PrimaryAccountDao extends CrudRepository<PrimaryAccount, Long> {
PrimaryAccount findByAccountNumber (int accountNumber);
}
```

AccountServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

@Autowired
private PrimaryAccountDao primaryAccountDao;

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

public void deposit(String accountType, double amount, Principal principal) {
    User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());

    if (accountType.equalsIgnoreCase("Primary")) {
        PrimaryAccount primaryAccount = user.getPrimaryAccount();
        primaryAccount.setAccountBalance(primaryAccount.getAccountBalance().add(new 
        BigDecimal(amount)));
        primaryAccountDao.save(primaryAccount);

        Date date = new Date();
```

//////FOLLOWING THE LINE WHERE ERROR COMES UP/////////////////////

```
        PrimaryTransaction primaryTransaction = new PrimaryTransaction(date, "Deposit to 
        Primary Account", "Account", "Finished", amount, primaryAccount.getAccountBalance());
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a no args constructor and a constructor with 7 arguments, but at the line where the erorr pops up you are passing only 6 values. I think you forgot `primaryAccount` as a last argument

Comment: Yes its true, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Constructor is expecting `primaryAccount` object as final parameter, so try like this,

```
PrimaryTransaction primaryTransaction = new PrimaryTransaction(date, "Deposit to Primary Account", "Account", "Finished", amount, primaryAccount);
```